# Не инкрементируется значение

Tags: golang, atomic

Пробую инкрементировать значение при помощи атомарных операций, но почему-то значение остается нулем, совсем не могу понять почему... вот код:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    //"time"
    "sync/atomic"
)

type st struct {
    workers int
    stop    chan bool
}

func main() {
    s := st{workers: 16}
    counter := s.Run()
    s.Stop()

    fmt.Println(counter)
}

func (s *st) Stop() {
    for i := 0; i < s.workers; i++ {
        s.stop <- true
    }
    close(s.stop)
}

func (s *st) Run() (counter int64) {
    schan := make(chan bool)
    s.stop = schan

    for i := 0; i < s.workers; i++ {
        go func()  {
            for {
                select {
                case <-s.stop:
                    return
                default:

                    atomic.AddInt64(&counter, 1)
                }
            }
        }()
    }

    return counter
}
```

Площадка: https://play.golang.org/p/Rhk9rqY0pzV

Comment: Не стоит ожидать от play.golang.org многого. Например, вот этот [пример](https://play.golang.org/p/xnPAATLiIdw) будет работать всегда по разному на локальной машине, в отличии от play.golang.org. Прошу посмотреть, как производится синхронизация.

Answer (score 1):

Все просто, у вас функция `Run()` отработала быстрей чем запустились горутины, соответственно  и значение вернулось 0. Я думаю, лучше переменную counter вынести как свойства структуры st, а потом ее выводить. Мой пример:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "sync/atomic"
)

type st struct {
    workers int
    stop    chan bool
    counter int64
}

func main() {
    s := st{workers: 16}
    s.Run()
    // Добавил Sleep т. к. есть вероятность того, что приложение остановится быстрей чем запустятся горутины
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    s.Stop()

    fmt.Println(s.Counter())
}

func (s *st) Stop() {
    for i := 0; i < s.workers; i++ {
        s.stop <- true
    }
    close(s.stop)
}

func (s *st) Run() {
    schan := make(chan bool)
    s.stop = schan
    s.counter = 0

    for i := 0; i < s.workers; i++ {
        go func(c *int64)  {
            for {
                select {
                case <-s.stop:
                    return
                default:
                    atomic.AddInt64(c, 1)
                }
            }
        }(&s.counter)
    }

}

func (s *st) Counter() int64 {
    return s.counter
}
```